# Android: In App purchase Query does not return any products(skuDetails)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on my first android app. I really learned a lot on stack overflow. But I with my current problem I did not find a solution yet.

I tried to implement "in app purchase". I did the following things:

1) In the developer console I uploaded a signed apk in alpha and beta test. I also added a test user to the account and for testing I am using that account. Additionally I added some "In app products(managed)" with the status active.

2) Like described on http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html I downloaded the necessary lib field, copied code from the example project TrivialDrive and followed all the steps which result to the coding:

```
// called when the app is started
public void setupConnectionToGooglePlay(final Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    mHelper = new IabHelper(context, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh no, there was a problem. --> no error message shown to
                // the user!
                Toast.makeText(context, "No connection to google:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "connection to google:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // If connection is established:
                get List of all in App Purchase products
                getListOfInAppPurchaseProducts();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When executing this part of code I get the result, that the connection was established successfully. Hence the method getListOfInAppPurchaseProducts() is called.

```
private void getListOfInAppPurchaseProducts() {
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // no error message is shown to the user
                Toast.makeText(context, "Query not successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String message = result.getMessage();
                boolean isSuccess = result.isSuccess();
                // no success message is shown to the user
                List<String> skus = inventory.getAllOwnedSkus();
                Map<String,SkuDetails> map = inventory.getSKUMap();
                int size = map.size();

                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Message: " + message + "Query successful. Mapsize:" + size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                WMGooglePlayConnection.this.inventory = inventory;

            }
        }
    };

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("test");
    list.add("test2");
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, list, mQueryFinishedListener);
}
```

Unfortunately the returned inventory does not contain any SKU Details (even the query is successful). I checked the following:

- productIds
- status of the product ids (active)
- base64EncodedPublicKey

For testing I used a real device (Samsung ACE 2). I copied the apk file directly to the device (not downloaded from google play). Can this be a problem?

Is it somehow possible to get the SKU Details also with the emulator?

Do you have any idea what I can check?

It would be really nice if someone could help me...

Comment: Yep, same here. I am guessing it's something from Google, because for us it used to work one week ago. If you find any solution though, please write it here.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this as well. Our in app billing stuff broke right around when Google Play Service 4.4 went out. A week or two back I think.

To get your in app billing products to show up now you'll have to publish your Alpha builds but have them only visible to people on your tester list/group.

After one publishes the app then testers can download it from the Google Play Store with a link similar to this.

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/

I hope this helps.