# OpenIAB - How to get prices from inventory?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using [OpenIAB](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/) library to manage InApp purchases on Androrid.

I'm trying to get dynamically the price set on Google Play of each item that you can purchase but `inventory.mSkuMap` and `inventory.getSkuDetails("SKU");` returns `NULL`.

I uploaded APK to Alpha channel yesterday, so I theoretically I shouldn't have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003174/271804)

I noticed that `mSkuMap` and `getSkuDetails()` retrieve data for items already purchased, so I'm confused because I thought that I retrieve all items with that and I should use `getAllPurchases()`or `getPurchase("SKU")` so, I'm wrong?

How can I retrieve purchasable items for my app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it replacing:

`mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);`

with

`mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skus, mGotInventoryListener);`

Comment: Can you explain how finally you got prices please?

Answer (score 0):

OpenIAB.queryInventory(new string[] {MONEY300G_ITEM_ID, MONEY500G_ITEM_ID});

It`s return sku local prices